# Ifelse() with three conditions

Tags: r

I have two vectors:

```
a<-rep(1:2,100)

b<-sample(a)
```

I would like to have an ifelse condition that compares each value of `a` with the corresponding value of `b`, and does the following:

```
if a>b 1
if a<b 0
if a=b sample(1:2,length(a),replace=T)
```

the first two can be done with :

```
ifelse(a>b,1,0)
```

but I'm not sure how to incorporate the case where `a` and `b` are equal.

Comment: consider also using `switch` which is meant for just this situation (where you have if/else/else/else...). Combining this with `apply` may get you to where you want to be, elegantly.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

How about adding another ifelse:

```
ifelse(a>b, 1, ifelse(a==b, sample(1:2, length(a), replace = TRUE), 0))
```

In this case you get the value 1 if a>b,  then, if a is equal to b it is either 1 or 2 (`sample(1:2, length(a), replace = TRUE)`), and if not (so a must be smaller than b) you get the value 0.

Comment: This will replicate `sample(1:2,1)` for each `a==b`.

Comment: `sample(1:2,1)` can be replaced with `sample(1:2, length(a), replace = TRUE)` or `sample(a)` now the OP has clarified that's what he wants.

Comment: I suggest using `sample(1:2, length(a), replace = TRUE)`, since not always will it have the same distribution as `sample(a)`.

Answer (score 10):

This is an easy way:

```
(a > b) + (a == b) * sample(2, length(a), replace = TRUE)
```

This is based on calculations with boolean values which are cast into numerical values.

Answer (score 8):

There is ambiguity in your question. Do you want different random values for all indexes where `a==b` or one random value for all indexes?

The answer by @Rob will work in the second scenario. For the first scenario I suggest avoiding `ifelse`:

```
u<-rep(NA,length(a))
u[a>b] <- 1
u[a<b] <- 0
u[a==b] <- sample(1:2,sum(a==b),replace=TRUE)
```

Comment: yes you are right, I want different random values for each index.